# New HashMap instance variable is not getting created for every request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

I have a SpringBoot application and I have declared a HashMap instance variable "**myMap**" in my service class like this:

```
public class MyService{
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addStates(String stateName){
myMap.put("state", stateName);
}

public void addCountries(String countryName){
myMap.put("country", countryName);
}
}
```

Say in my 1st HTTP request I have called this class and myMap values are

[("state","Kerala"),("country","India")]

---

2nd request myMap values should be

[("state","Orissa"),("country","India")]

But **actual** map values in 2nd request is

[("state","Kerala"),("country","India")],
[("state","Orissa"),("country","India")]

Seems like 1st **myMap** variable created is used in subsequent requests also, I want new map variable getting created for every request. I cannot add it as method variable as this is used in so many methods across the class.

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: Services have to be stateless, there should not be any variable like `myMap` in a service class. Why do you currently have one? If all fails you can annotate some things as "request scope", but you should firstly think about wether that is even needed and if you should instead fix your application structure. What happens to `myMap`, who writes it, who reads it, where is it used? Your example is too simple right now.

Comment: myMap is passed to an external API as input argument

Comment: Every time you call your methods int the same scope, new values are keep getting added to your map. Don't know your goal, but either split up your concerns, add two lists (caching) for each method or remove the "state" completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the scope of a bean in spring is `Singleton`. So in your case the `MyService` class will be treated by spring as singleton. So normally only one object of your service class will be created and same will be used for all the request.
If you want your service class object to be created for per request in such case you can sue the `Request` scope of the bean.

```
@Service
@Scope("request")
public class MyService{
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addStates(String stateName){
myMap.put("state", stateName);
}

public void addCountries(String countryName){
myMap.put("country", countryName);
}
}
```

Comment: But this is no longer a service, this is basically a Pojo, no need for `@Service`, rename the class to `MyMapData` and create it via `new MyMapData()` within the request handler.

Comment: Don't know if his service class is having more of businesses logic. So can't exactly say this is not a service class

Comment: I don't know either but I know that *if* it has service methods those should be removed. Either it is a service OR it has state, both together should not ever happen.

Comment: I can already see OP accepting this answer, using request scope everywhere and messing up their nice and clean spring application.

Comment: I too agree with you. But there is not fixed rules like that and sometimes based on requirements you need to have some out of the box solutions.

Comment: And I don't think at all the using of the request scope does mess with spring cleanness. If so the request scope could have been deprecated and removed log back

Comment: This is a service class, ya adding request scope is one alternative. I was thinking of myMap.clear() also. But I guess it might mess up thread synchronisation.

Comment: @luk2302 if you think a service **can't** have state, then you must've missed the (stateless/stateful) Enterprise JavaBeans craze. Stateless services are far more common, but there's no rule against state.